# FakeRequest withMultipartFormDataBody "Missing boundary header"

Tags: scala, testing, playframework

I am writing controller tests with Play 2.6

I have a file upload that absolutely works outside test scenario
but when I do a fake request, I get stuck with this:

```
A client error occurred: Missing boundary header
```

here is my request:

> ```
>     def createMultipartFile(file: File) : MultipartFormData[TemporaryFile] = {
>       MultipartFormData(Map[String,Seq[String]](),
>         List(FilePart("file","",Some("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"),SingletonTemporaryFileCreator.create(file.toPath))), List())
>     }
>     val data = createMultipartFile(sampleCSV)
>     val controller = app.injector.instanceOf[RefundableController]
>     val request = FakeRequest().withMultipartFormDataBody(data)
>     val result = controller.func().apply(request)
>     assert(status(result) === 200)
> ```

tried adding a header manually but that obviously didn't work

how am i supposed to add a boundary?

Answer (score 1):

It helped when I simply changed `withMultipartFormDataBody` to `withBody`.
Found this idea [here](https://github.com/jroper/playframework/blob/a89c4667afb99295b7c5a74f986fb25c1c9abd21/documentation/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/upload/code/ScalaFileUpload.scala).